# firefox not displaying SOME svg files but works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

html

```
<li><a href="#" class="email connectWith"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="twitter connectWith"></a></li>
```

css

```
/*this svg is displayed in firefox*/
.email{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url("../images/email.svg");
    background-position: 0 0;
}

/*this one not*/
.twitter{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url("../images/twitter.svg");
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

svg code(email and twitter file)

---

email

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="50px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 50 100" enable-background="new 0 0 50 100" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path fill="#BDC3C7" d="M50,25c0,13.807-11.193,25-25,25l0,0C11.193,50,0,38.807,0,25l0,0C0,11.193,11.193,0,25,0l0,0
        C38.807,0,50,11.193,50,25L50,25z"/>
    <g>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M39.203,20.306c0,0-13.034,10.387-13.604,10.836c-0.569,0.45-1.289,0-1.289,0s-13.03-10.383-13.464-10.817
            c-0.434-0.435-0.709,0.11-0.709,0.11v13.794c0,1.055,0.863,1.917,1.917,1.917h25.889c1.055,0,1.918-0.863,1.918-1.917V20.465
            C39.603,20.076,39.203,20.306,39.203,20.306z"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M37.944,13.853H12.055c-1.04,0-1.892,0.791-1.916,1.765l-0.002,0v0.168c0,0,13.559,10.797,14.203,11.237
            s1.199-0.015,1.199-0.015l9.4-7.365l0.021-0.016l4.902-3.841v-0.127C39.862,14.666,38.999,13.853,37.944,13.853z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <path fill="#E74C3C" d="M50,75c0,13.808-11.192,25-25,25l0,0C11.193,100,0,88.807,0,75l0,0c0-13.807,11.193-25,25-25l0,0
        C38.808,50,50,61.193,50,75L50,75z"/>
    <g>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M39.204,70.305c0,0-13.035,10.388-13.604,10.837s-1.288,0-1.288,0s-13.03-10.383-13.464-10.817
            c-0.434-0.435-0.709,0.11-0.709,0.11v13.794c0,1.055,0.863,1.917,1.917,1.917h25.89c1.055,0,1.918-0.862,1.918-1.917V70.464
            C39.604,70.076,39.204,70.305,39.204,70.305z"/>
        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M37.945,63.853h-25.89c-1.04,0-1.892,0.79-1.916,1.765l-0.002-0.001v0.169
            c0,0,13.559,10.797,14.203,11.236s1.198-0.015,1.198-0.015l9.401-7.365l0.02-0.016l4.903-3.841v-0.128
            C39.863,64.666,39,63.853,37.945,63.853z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

---

twitter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="50px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 50 100" enable-background="new 0 0 50 100" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path fill="#BDC3C7" d="M50,25c0,13.807-11.193,25-25,25l0,0C11.193,50,0,38.807,0,25l0,0C0,11.193,11.193,0,25,0l0,0
        C38.807,0,50,11.193,50,25L50,25z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M39.27,16.148c-1.05,0.466-2.178,0.781-3.362,0.922c1.209-0.725,2.137-1.872,2.574-3.24
        c-1.132,0.671-2.385,1.159-3.718,1.421c-1.068-1.138-2.59-1.849-4.274-1.849c-3.233,0-5.855,2.622-5.855,5.855
        c0,0.458,0.052,0.906,0.151,1.334c-4.866-0.244-9.181-2.575-12.068-6.118c-0.504,0.865-0.793,1.871-0.793,2.944
        c0,2.031,1.034,3.824,2.604,4.874c-0.959-0.03-1.862-0.294-2.652-0.732c0,0.024,0,0.049,0,0.074c0,2.837,2.018,5.204,4.697,5.741
        c-0.492,0.134-1.009,0.206-1.543,0.206c-0.377,0-0.744-0.037-1.102-0.105c0.745,2.326,2.908,4.019,5.47,4.066
        c-2.004,1.57-4.529,2.506-7.272,2.506c-0.473,0-0.938-0.028-1.397-0.082c2.591,1.662,5.669,2.631,8.976,2.631
        c10.77,0,16.66-8.922,16.66-16.66c0-0.254-0.006-0.506-0.017-0.757C37.492,18.354,38.484,17.323,39.27,16.148z"/>
</g>
<path fill="#4099FF" d="M50,75c0,13.808-11.192,25-25,25l0,0C11.193,100,0,88.807,0,75l0,0c0-13.807,11.193-25,25-25l0,0
    C38.808,50,50,61.193,50,75L50,75z"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M39.271,66.149c-1.05,0.465-2.179,0.78-3.363,0.922c1.209-0.725,2.138-1.872,2.575-3.24
    c-1.132,0.671-2.385,1.159-3.719,1.421c-1.068-1.138-2.59-1.849-4.273-1.849c-3.234,0-5.856,2.621-5.856,5.855
    c0,0.459,0.052,0.905,0.152,1.334c-4.867-0.244-9.181-2.575-12.068-6.118c-0.504,0.865-0.793,1.871-0.793,2.944
    c0,2.031,1.034,3.823,2.604,4.873c-0.959-0.03-1.863-0.294-2.652-0.732c0,0.024,0,0.05,0,0.074c0,2.837,2.018,5.203,4.697,5.741
    c-0.491,0.134-1.009,0.205-1.542,0.205c-0.377,0-0.744-0.037-1.102-0.104c0.745,2.326,2.907,4.019,5.469,4.066
    c-2.004,1.57-4.528,2.506-7.271,2.506c-0.473,0-0.939-0.027-1.397-0.081c2.591,1.661,5.669,2.63,8.976,2.63
    c10.771,0,16.659-8.922,16.659-16.659c0-0.254-0.006-0.507-0.017-0.758C37.493,68.354,38.485,67.323,39.271,66.149z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The email.svg file is displayed properly in firefox but twitter.svg is not displayed but both are working fine with chrome and IE, tried re-saving the files with same specifications in illustrator but getting the same result. Not sure where the problem is, tried add a style like:

```
svg{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

still getting the same results.

Comment: Does it work if you open the file in Firefox, i.e. not in the context of your website?

Comment: Is mime type ok on your server config?

Comment: @Prinzhorn yes works when I directly open it in firefox.

Comment: @Emergento, must be since other .svg file works. I guess.

Comment: The MIME type can easily be checked in the Dev Tools of your browser, or a tool like the excellent Fiddler. It **is** worth looking at, you cannot simply make the assumption that it is correct because some files work. Once you have a known fault, it is then the time to start investigating and disregarding assumptions - this is the process of fault finding. Checking logically and in turn. It will also be well worthwhile checking the console within Dev Tools to see if any errors are reported there.

Comment: Can you share your markup? The error may well be there as your image works as a background image unmodified in Firefox locally, using your original CSS. There are wasted nodes in the Twitter image that can safely be deleted to reduce its size slightly, but the background image worked correctly both with and without these.

Comment: @pwdst, added my html. I think that is the important part needed.

Comment: @pwdst, I can't see twitter.svg listed under Media tab in firefox. Other one(email) is listed there. Seems like it isn't loaded at all.

Comment: With reference to the markup, I'd suggest adding the text "Twitter" and "Email" inside the links, since you've gone to the trouble of setting text-indent to be so large that it will almost certainly be off the screen (this is good for accessibility and SEO as the text can then by read by non-sighted users, without affecting visual appearance). Back to the problem can I suggest looking at the "Network" tab in your dev tools, or downloading and running the excellent Fiddler web debugging tool, to see what request and response is made - including the MIME type and status code of the response?

Comment: looked into Network tab, there is no request for twitter.svg. Not sure on how find the MIME type you are saying. haha! sorry a bit dumb!

Comment: Post an example somewhere so we can look at the real thing, not just snippets.  There is nothing particularly obviously wrong from what you have already posted.

Comment: you might want to cleanup your SVG that is exported from Illustrator using this online SVG cleanup and optimizing tool. ..  https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ .. sometimes Firefox will not display SVG at all or propertly if it is malformed or is full of extra illustrator mumbo jumbo in its path data `d` attribute